# "Steam needs to be online to update" error while updating Steam

Tags: steam

Someone please help me with this. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Steam multiple times, and the error continues to occur.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: I had this happen when I tried to go back to playing Civ V after a year or so. Worked fine the next day and on a different (faster) network.

Comment: Is your Network fully connected or are there sometimes short down-times ? Maybe your connection gets cut off and then steam loses pakages and screws up the update ?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have a stable internet connection while updating Steam. Perhaps your connection drops while updating Steam which messes up the whole process and forces you to do it again. If that doesn't work, I recommend deleting and reinstalling Steam one more time. Out of curiosity, what operating system are you running?

I forget to mention that you should try a different wifi network to see if you get the same problem while updating Steam. Cheers!